# Regex in SQL split() to convert a comma separated string enclosed in square brackets into an array and remove the surrounding quotes from each element

Tags: regex, apache-spark-sql, split, azure-databricks

I have string data column with values like this:

```
 - ["some val1"]
 - []
 - ["some val2", "some_val3"]
 - single value without brackets and quotes
 - [[]
 - ["val with "quote 1", "val with "quote and bracket["]
```

I want to convert the values into arrays, so the array column would look like:

```
 - 0: some val1 
 - 0: null
 - 0: some val2  
   1: some val3
 - 0: single value without brackets and quotes
 - 0: [
 - 0: val with "quote 1
   1: val with "quote and bracket[
```

How can I split such data into an array (I assume, spark-sql function `split()` can be used for that)?

Currently I use this code, but it doesn't remove the surrounding quotes from each element + I feel overall it could be done by using just simple regex passed to the `split()` function without using of `ltrim`/`rtrim`.

```
with cte as
(select '["some val1"]' as val
 union all
 select '[]'
 union all
 select '["some val2", "some_val3"]'
 union all
 select 'single value without brackets and quotes'
 union all
 select '[[]'
 union all
 select '["val with "quote 1", "val with "quote and bracket["]')

select
  split(ltrim('[', rtrim(']', val)), ',') as array_val
from cte
```

**upd:** Updated sample data + some summary: I need to remove only single pair of enclosing brackets around the source value, and only single pair of enclosing quotes around each element. Also I tried this code, but it doesn't remove the first quote from the 2nd element of the array:

```
transform(split(regexp_replace(val, '^[\\[]|[\\]]$', ''), ','), x -> regexp_replace(x, '^["]|["]$', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got output as below.

[image]

Here, the strings are surrounded by `\"` and no `null` if it is empty string.

So, I modified the query as below and got output.

```
with cte as
(select  '["some val1"]'  as val
 union  all
 select  '[]'
 union  all
 select  '["some val2", "some_val3"]'
 union  all
 select  'single value without brackets and quotes')

select
trim('[]',regexp_replace(val,'"' ,'' )) as array_val,
case
    when  instr(array_val,',') >  0  then
        split(array_val,',')
    when  len(array_val)==0  then
        array(null)
    else
        array(array_val)
end  as nt
from cte
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I need to remove only single pair of enclosing brackets around the source value, and only single pair of enclosing quotes around each element

Comment: Ok. Add your sample data in the question.

Comment: @archjkeee Try this `select 
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(val, '^\\["|"\\]$|^\\[|\\]$', ''),'"\\s*,\\s*"',',') as array_val`
and add case statements given in solution for split and null.